# Why does Assert.AreEqual Fail on <Object, Object>? Type Mismatch?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest, assert

I'm trying to use `Assert.AreEqual` in a test to validate a DTO from our provider.

The assert is failing with:

> **Expected:** DTO.EmployeeDTO
>
> **Actual:** DataProviders.Mappers.EmployeeMapper

Is there something I can do with our DTO and/or mapper to get `AreEqual` working? Should I override `Equals` for the DTO and use `Assert.Equal` instead?

**Here is our expected employee DTO for comparison:**

```
EmployeeDTO expected = new EmployeeDTO
{
    Category = "OPS", 
    Code = "EMPL",
    Email = "bill.gates@microsoft.com",
    JobDescription = "Philanthropist",
    FirstName = "Bill",
    Bolander = "Gates",
    ResourceID = 1234567,
    ResourceNumber = "ABCD1234567",
    UserGUID = Guid.Parse("0A76A348-B709-9EF0-9E44-419433E7C90D"),
    UserName = "billygates"
};
```

**Here is our call from the data provider, which should return an `EmployeeDTO` that we can compare to our expected DTO.**

```
 EmployeeDTO actual = controller.GetEmployee("billygates");
```

**Here is the `GetEmployee` provider method which should return an employee DTO:**

```
public EmployeeDTO GetEmployee(string userName)
{
    EmployeeDTO toReturn = null;

    //Get employee   
    toReturn = (from employees in Context.EmployeeTable
       where employees.UserName.Equals(userName)
       select new EmployeeMapper
       {
        MapToFullDTO = employees
       }
       ).SingleOrDefault<EmployeeDTO>();
}
```

Note that the `MapToFullDTO` property is part of a class called `EmployeeMapper` which inherits from `EmployeeDTO`. This property populates the base classes' properties for convenience purposes so we don't have to write out the mapping every time. I understand this is part of the issue, but I am not sure why.

Comment: I'd use Extension Methods syntax here, e.g. `Context.EmployeeTable.Where(e => e.UserName.Equals(userName))
                      .Select(e => new EmployeeMapper { apToFullDTO = e }) to do not mess with Query Syntax.
                      .SingleOrDefault<EmployeeDTO>()`.

Comment: Just a side comment totally unrelated to your question, I'm about syntax and styles. You mess up in the LINQ query two syntaxes: so called "query" and "extension methods". For readability it's better to stick with one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to override `Equals()` method on the class to compare the objects based on properties' values.

Otherwise the comparison will compare the references of the objects which are obviously different.